Do solids also follow the reverse of this equation?
We all know the equation for linear thermal expansion on heating the solid
$$\Delta L = \alpha L \Delta T $$
Now I know solids expand on heating, for example in railway tracks in summers but after some time when they lose heat the do come back to normal.
So I have always wondered if this equation works if the $\Delta T$ is  $-ve$, i.e., we decrease the temperature would $\Delta L$ become $-ve$, decreasing its length? If not then how do railway tracks go back to normal after some time?

Just to clarify - many materials have a negative thermal expansion coefficient over some temperature range. This is well known in many polymer materials in normal human-friendly temperature ranges, but, e.g., silicon below 40K or so has a negative coefficient.

@JonCuster so do those materials contract on heating? Can you name one or two, or perhaps provide a paper about them please?

I edited your post to replace unicode with MathJax (which looks like Donald Knuth's LaTex, which is the best).

"...if the $\Delta T$ is  $-ve$..." What is this supposed to mean. Your id est does not seem to explain what your symbols mean. "[W]ould $\Delta L$ become $-ve$..." Obviously not, since that is also the value of $\Delta T$ in your example.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_expansion#:~:text=Fairly%20pure%20silicon%20has%20a,a%20wide%20range%20of%20temperatures. for silicon

@JEB thank you jeb

@hft by ∆L being negative I meant if the length would contract on freezing the solid

Yes, thermal contraction happens when the tracks cool off. In fact this effect is commonly used to get a tight fit between two pieces of metal that fit into each other, as follows:
For the case of a peg that must fit extremely tightly into a hole in a piece of metal, the hole is drilled too small to begin with- but then the piece is heated and the peg is chilled, so they can easily be fit together. Then the chilled peg warms up and the drilled piece cools off to form a shrink fit that becomes almost impossible to take apart again.

So ∆L being negative is possible?, I always wondered about it so can I use the Newton's law of cooling to know how the length contracts over time as -dT/dt = K (T-T0), and can you tell me how K is found is it the same constant from the Fourier law of conducting of heat ∆Q/∆t = -kA∆T/∆x? And thanks for the response

For future reference: $-\frac{dT}{dt} = K(T-T_0)$ and $ \frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t} = -kA\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta x}$.
